# Deriving Time from Acceleration, Displacement, and Initial Velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, time, velocity, displacement

I know the equation for displacement as a function of time is $$\vec{s} = \vec{v_i}  \Delta{t}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}\,(\Delta t)^2$$
I need to solve for $\Delta t$ I'm having problems rearranging to do this. As of now, I created a Python program to run through the displacement formula, adding a set amount of time in each iteration, until the displacement is equal to the displacement I am looking for. I feel that this is woefully inefficient, inaccurate, and horribly CPU intensive. I am confident that this is possible to rearrange, and that I have missed something.

If someone already know what this formula rearranged to solve for $\Delta t$ is, I'd much appreciate it if you would share it with me. In the meantime, I shall continue to look around for the rearranged formula and keep trying to solve for $\Delta t$.

Hopefully I have not missed something painfully obvious, and that I am not wasting anyone's time.

Comment: Perhaps you should read about [quadratic equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

Comment: Heck... why not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Comment: I imagine that part of the "horriby CPU intensive" is the fact that you're using a interpreted language rather than a compiled language (e.g., Fortran90+ or C/C++).

Comment: @KyleKanos actually, its because I have the differences in time set to like 0.000000001 seconds. Not "Hard on CPU" like that, but CPU intensive because it runs through the equation 10000 times in 40 secs.

Comment: @CoilKid... so what you are really saying is that not only do you not know how to solve quadratic equations, you also don't know how to program an iterative solver... which, unfortunately, is strongly correlated with your lack of math skills at this point. Computers only work well for you, if you know how to work computers well...

Comment: @CuriousOne I never said it didn't work I never said it didn't work well. When I said "Horribly inaccurate" I meant that its inaccurate if I don't want to wait 3 minutes. And I _do_ know how to program iterative solvers. The whole point of this question was asking if anyone know how to do this _without_ a solver.

Comment: @CoilKid: Sorry, but if you can't do a simple quadratic equation, chances that you can do an iterative solver (which relies on more math than that) are slim to none. That your program needs 3 minutes on the equivalent of a 1990s supercomputer to calculate a result for which a closed form solution has been known since the time of the ancient Egyptians doesn't bode well for your statement, either.

Comment: @CuriousOne Look. Yes, believe it or no, I made a _working_ iterative solver. I _can_ do quadratics, but this one is throwing me. Perhaps it shouldn't. Perhaps this problem is stupidly simple. Perhaps the answer is looking me in the face. Perhaps all of that is true. Haven't you ever had a day where absolutely nothing seems to be going right?

Comment: @CoilKid: I had plenty of days when nothing worked right... but after a while you stop complaining about it and you sleep it off. You sound very young, so you don't have to worry about all of this. In reality, I can tell you, that some of us (myself included), are envying your for your naive question. At least I can remember when I did stuff like that, and it was so much cooler than all the things I did later in life. We get used to doing "grand stuff" like at CERN very fast, and the novelty wears off. But I can still remember when my first program solved the Kepler problem correctly! Peace!

Comment: @CuriousOne You made a program that solved the Kepler problem? Also, I'm not complaining. I was hoping to finish this today. I have to start building my project by the 15th. I'd like to finish all the math before I build. I suppose I _could_ just sleep off the bad day, but its so much more invigorating to get something to work on a bad day than to procrastinate until tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, wow. I cannot believe I missed that. I could just apply the quadratic formula... Wow... Yeah, not my best day. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time. Thanks for the all help provided.

Comment: Okay, someone please correct me if I got this wrong, but applying the quadratic formula, I get $\Delta t=\frac{-Vi \pm \sqrt{Vi^2 + 2aS}}{a}$.

Comment: @CoilKid - yes you got it right. I had not noticed the later comments (they were hidden) when I wrote my answer or I might not have bothered. But yes, you got it. Now you may understand why some people were being a little dismissive - they were having a hard time understanding why you were having a hard time understanding… and now you too have a hard time wondering why you didn't see it to begin with. As CuriousOne said - we all have days like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly have a vector equation, then you really have three quadratic equations - one each for the X, Y and Z component.

Let's write them:

$$s_x = v_x \Delta t + \frac12 a_x (\Delta t)^2\\
s_y = v_y \Delta t + \frac12 a_y (\Delta t)^2\\
s_z = v_z \Delta t + \frac12 a_z (\Delta t)^2$$

If there is only one value of $\Delta t$, then this is an overdetermined set of equations: three equations, one unknown. This means that the values of acceleration and velocity have to be exactly right if you want to be able to solve them.

But assuming that this is the case, then the solution (after simply rearranging) is the solution to the quadratic equation:

$$\frac12 a t^2 + v t - s = 0$$
(I dropped some suffixes to make it easier to write). We solve for $t$ with the usual:

$$t = \frac{-v \pm \sqrt{v^2 + 2as}}{a}$$

Answer (score 1):

You've written a vector equation, but any solution involving numbers has to involve one coordinate at a time, or what amounts to the same thing, three simultaneous equations.

For simplicity, let's assume a one-dimensional version.  All of the displacements, velocities, and the acceleration point in the same direction: $$s = v_i\Delta t + 1/2\, a\,(\Delta t)^2$$

This might be more recognizable:  a quadratic equation in $\Delta t$.